# two tomcat installed in single Ec2 server with same port and IP address

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have two tomcat installed in single Ec2 server with different directory and has single website.
tomcat1 path: /var/lib/tomcat (tomcat version 7)
tomcat2 path: /opt/tomcat  (tomcat version 9)

tomcat1 and tomcat2 of server.xml file are all of the same with no different.(port, protocol,..)

tomcat1 (server.xml)

tomcat2 (server.xml)

when I connect localhost:8080 ,show tomcat version 7.
when checked server status,two tomcat are active running.
I would like to know this server which tomcat is running.tomcat1 or tomcat2?
Please Help me.thanks a lot.

when I connect localhost:8080 ,show tomcat version 7.
when checked server status,two tomcat are active running.
I would like to know this server which tomcat is running.tomcat1 or tomcat2?

Comment: If tomcat1 is v7, then the one that opened the port is tomcat1, no?